# click on a button in another application from my C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, api

I want to click on a button in another application from my C# application ,
and I don't have the source code for the application that contains the button

let us say as an example ...can I use windows calculator from my application by clicking its buttons Programmatically
I am using c# and .NET
I think I must use windows api to do this
does anybody have any idea????

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's not too complicated. You can use FindWindowEx to get the window handle, then iterate through the windows elements and use sendmessage or postmessage to send the WM_Click message.

Here's a codeproject project that does exactly what you want.

[Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowsAPIsFromCS.aspx)

Comment: It should still respond to low-level window messages like WM_Click. WPF is just another way to organize the controls in development, really; it's still built up into a Windows GUI object collection.

Comment: I've tried the code in the link above, but it will only work in Windows XP, not 7 or 8. Buttons in Calculator do not respond. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: For people looking for the value WM_Click is 0x00F5

Comment: @KeithS: WPF doesn't use native Windows controls, and never has. You might be confusing this with WIndows Forms. For WPF there really aren't any `HWND`s to send messages to. And that's a good thing, too, because it forces developers to reconsider, and pick the tool that was meant to be used: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). Oh, and -1, for the sloppiness alone. There is no `WM_Click` message in the Windows API.

Comment: I also tried this code and it doesn't work for the calculator in Windows 10