# SFX Install Button

Tags: c#, sfx

I am working on a program that needs to extract a WinRar SFX automatically.  Is there anyway I can programmatically click a install button once the exe is started with a Process?  Here is the code that I have so far.

```
public bool Extract()
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = FilePath;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = FilePath + fileName;

            process.Start();

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [click on a button in another application from my C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899573/click-on-a-button-in-another-application-from-my-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the sfx silent with winrar.

[Here is a link](http://windowsmatters.com/2011/08/27/using-winrar-sfx-to-create-a-silent-install-package/)

Comment: I am not making the winrar.  It is a file we are downloading.

Comment: And you need to run it? You could use dotnetzip and extracts it

Comment: Is there a way to change the directory when extracting with dotnetzip?  Ex. The program is in C:/programs but the exe is in C:/Downloads

Comment: Yes you can, see this http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/5aa95a4f-09cd-2f4a-9b0f-92ee223b075b.htm