# Invoke a method from another process

Tags: c#, button, methods, process, gettype

I have an application I got from work. Now I'm trying to program the ability to automatically click a button. For this to work, I need to get inside.

I can easily see the source code with a decompiler, so I know all the class names, method names, etc...

I've been looking into Types and the Type.GetMethod() Method. Only problem is that I try to work with the process of the app. I capture the right app (Process.GetProcessByName("WorkProcess")), I can capture the 'Type', but I don't know how to get to the right class, and invoke the right method.

I'll give you a layout that's shown in the decompiler:

```
WorkApp
> WorkApp.Exe
--> References
--> <Default namespace>
--> WORKAPP
----> frmsomething (Form)
------> _btnsync : Button
------> btnsync : Button
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I searched google, but couldn't find an answer...

Thank you
Anthony

PS: I don't have access to the source code of the app from work.

PPS: This is the code I have thusfar:

```
    Process WA = null;

    private void Initialize()
    {
        Process[] pa = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process p in pa)
        {
            if (p.ProcessName.Contains("WorkApp"))
            {
                WA = p;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (WA == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App was not found...");
            stop = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Type t = WA.GetType();
            t.GetType();
            // This is the place I got stuck
        }
    }
```

Comment: `WA.GetType()` will return `System.Diagnostics.Process`, and `t.GetType()` will return `System.Type`, both of which are useless for your purpose. Also, a process doesn't have to be a CLR process. Why don't you send a message to the relevant button? See [click on a button in another application from my C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899573/click-on-a-button-in-another-application-from-my-c-sharp-application).

Comment: I'd like to do that, the only problem being that the button I want to push is inside another process, created by this app. When open, you see the two in the task manager, but the 2nd form can only be opened by a contextmenu.

Comment: Yeah so first send a message indicating you want to Invoke that menu.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you are trying to invoke a method in an application from outside world of it, one way is to Create Remote thread in that application, and using that dll from inside that application, do the work using Reflection.
I did this to an application and it worked.
if you want details, comment on my answer.

Comment: Do you mean injecting a dll? (PS wasn't me who -1 you)

Comment: Yes thats what i meant