# Create a button from other script in c#

Tags: c#, button

Hi I have one built created with one script in c# but now I want to create a button from other script in the same Form (the same window) that in the first script.
Would be great to use a `PlayButton_Click void` from different script too.

Here is an example of what i'm trying:

Script 1:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class HelloWorld : Form
{
  public static Button PlayButton;

  public void Main()
  {
    Application.Run ();
  }

  public Form1()
  {
    PlayButton = new Button();
    Controls.Add(PlayButton);
  }

  public void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show ("All ok");
  }
}
```

Script 2:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HelloWorld2 : Form
{
  public static Button PlayButton2;

    public Helloworld2()
    {
        PlayButton2 = new Button();
        Controls.Add(PlayButton2);
    }

    public void PlayButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("I'm in the first Form :D!");
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want a form with two buttons? Why don't you use the designer to add them?

Comment: so Do you have 2 independent programms? if YES that means that you need to get the handle of the display first form. If you have only 1 program with 2 different forms then you need to pass the object of the first form as a parameter to the second form.

Comment: You never subscribe to the event `Click` of the `PlayButton2` object.

Comment: and you need to register the click events `PlayButton_Click` and `PlayButton2_Click` otherwise they are useless

Comment: I'm doing all programmatically just for learning

Comment: @MongZhu not sure about two different programs, it could be two different forms in one program, but question is not very clear.

Comment: basically you are asking the same question as [click on a button in another application from my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899573/click-on-a-button-in-another-application-from-my-c-sharp-application)

Comment: @bradbury9 you're right, i rephrased my comment

Comment: so how do you intend to add the button? via a method that you want to call or via the button click?

Comment: @Mong Zhu Sorry I'm very newbie. The first script creates one window with one button, I just want to add in the same window another button from script2. What is the best way?

Comment: please explain by what you mean with "script".

Comment: do you have both classes in the same project? do you have only 1 `Program.cs` in your solution ?

Comment: @sLw with script I mean .cs

Comment: @Mong zhu I have 2 `SharpFiles.cs` in my solution. I'm trying to create the button from the second one. And I want to make it appear in the same window (when I build the solution) than the first .cs file.

Comment: You wouldn't even see the two buttons if you got it to work. There's much that's wrong with that code. For example you don't set a location, which means they would overlap. First get everything working, then ask again

Comment: @sLw I know they will overlap like that, that is not exactly my code cos my code is very long, that is just an example.

Comment: A simple way would be to just pass over the first form and then just add the button to that form instead of the 2nd

Comment: please tell us how you want to display the second form `HelloWorld2` ?